# ws2007FederationHttpBinding and WIF delegation

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wif

I have a website that logs in using an STS, then gets a delegated token using the bootstrap token.  I am then trying to use the delgated token to connect to a WCF service.  I believe its my WCF config thats wrong.  I've tried so many different configurations I'm lost.

I've gotten various errors from "Description    Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found." To Audience URI missing in the SAML token.

I'm fairly sure its the federated configurations.

Any ideas would be helpful!!

Or anybody have an example of delegation to a wcf service?

Thanks!

This is the channel factory code.

```
  private static IService1 GetServiceProxy(SecurityToken token)
    {
        var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(
            binding,
            new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress));
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        factory.ConfigureChannelFactory();

        var channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
        return channel;

    }
```

This is the services config.  I've got 3 various sub-bindings that i've tried as well.

```
  <system.serviceModel>

  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
                    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
                    logKnownPii="true"
                    logEntireMessage="true" 
                    logMalformedMessages="true" />
  </diagnostics>

  <bindings>

    <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ServiceHost_Service1">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey">
            <issuerMetadata address="https://localhost/sts2/issue/wstrust/mex"/>
            <issuer address="http://localhost/sts2/issue/wstrust/message/username" 
                    binding="ws2007HttpBinding" 
                    bindingConfiguration="https://localhost/sts2/issue/wstrust/message/username">
              <identity>
                <certificate encodedValue="certblahblah"/>
              </identity>  
            </issuer>
            <tokenRequestParameters></tokenRequestParameters>
          </message>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>

    <ws2007HttpBinding>

      <binding name="https://localhost/sts2/issue/wstrust/mixed/username"
            closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
            transactionFlow="false"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text"
            textEncoding="utf-8"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                      maxStringContentLength="8192"
                      maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true"
                         inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                         enabled="false" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                     proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                   negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                   algorithmSuite="Default"
                   establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>

      <binding name="https://localhost/sts2/issue/wstrust/mixed/certificate"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             transactionFlow="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true"
             allowCookies="false">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                      maxStringContentLength="8192"
                      maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true"
                         inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                         enabled="false" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                     proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"
                   negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                   algorithmSuite="Default"
                   establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>

      <binding name="https://localhost/sts2/issue/wstrust/message/username"
            closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
            sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
            transactionFlow="false"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text"
            textEncoding="utf-8"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                      maxStringContentLength="8192"
                      maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true"
                         inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                         enabled="false" />
        <security mode="Message">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
                     proxyCredentialType="None"
                     realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                   negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                   algorithmSuite="Default"
                   establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>

    </ws2007HttpBinding>
  </bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <federatedServiceHostConfiguration/>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate  findValue="1d076d8f9dff87a44b59d09ec0e1bc60"
                  storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                  storeName="My"
                  x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber">
        </serviceCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>

    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="federatedServiceHostConfiguration"
             type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.ConfigureServiceHostBehaviorExtensionElement, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<services>
  <service name="ServiceHost_Service1">
    <endpoint binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="ServiceHost_Service1"
              contract="ServiceHost.IService1">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="localhost"/>
        <certificate encodedValue="certblahblah"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<!--<client>
  <endpoint binding="customBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="ServiceHost_Service1"
            contract="ServiceHost.IService1">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="localhost"/>
      <certificate encodedValue="certblahblahblah"/>
    </identity>        
  </endpoint>

</client>-->

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

This is the identity config

```
 <microsoft.identityModel>
```

```
<certificateValidation revocationMode="NoCheck"
                       certificateValidationMode="None" />
<issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
  <trustedIssuers>
    <add thumbprint="c4e675b5add2a7d6d59bbd5e04ca30b440e23eff"
            name="Thinktecture.IdentityServer" />
  </trustedIssuers>
</issuerNameRegistry>

<federatedAuthentication>
  <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false"
                issuer="https://localhost/sts2/issue/wsfed"
                realm="https://localhost/ServiceHost/" />
  <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
</federatedAuthentication>

<serviceCertificate>
  <certificateReference findValue="1d076d8f9dff87a44b59d09ec0e1bc60"
                  storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                  storeName="My"
                  x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
</serviceCertificate>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, William?

Comment: No, I basically scrapped the code, started over with the minimalist configuration, and got it working.  It was something in the WCF binding config, but I never went back and checked exactly what line it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to figure out the active STS / WCF delegation scenario myself and cobbled together a sample project (note that security checks themselves are turned off, this project was to help me understand the flow and dependencies):

https://github.com/colinbowern/TwoTierSts